# The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know about Computer Science (No Excuses!)

Tags: education, applied-theory

Yes, I borrowed the title form a famous [joelonsoftware post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for my question because I didn't exactly know how to ask this.

I'm a professional programmer for a few years now and although I followed informatics courses in school there was a lot of stuff missing from the curriculum, as I now know but wasn't aware then. For example I didn't do any compiler theory, algorithm analysis (the Big-O), have no idea what P-NP meant etc.

So I want to catch up now!

But the field of computer science is big. Really big! So from here my question: What's the absolute minimum every software developer absolutely, positively must know about computer science (no excuses!)?

Comment: It might depend on what type of development you do.

Comment: Should you not ask this on [programmers.SE]? It's a very broad question; what area are you interested in most?  It's also an subjective question; you can enable objective answers by explaining a particular task you feel could profit from CS knowledge. You might want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) to get some ideas, too.

Comment: @Raphael: I'm interested in the areas that would benefit a software developer nowadays, someone that does Java, PHP, C#, Java, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, MVC, CRM, eBanking etc work (i.e. the corporate developer). For example I'm learning Haskell right now and although lambda calculus would be a nice thing to know it's not what most developers do right now, and not in Haskell since from a company's point of view that's an exotic (i.e. risky) technology. I wish I could point to some topics, but as I said, the things I learned in school weren't much.

Comment: @Raphael: The more I think about it the more I think you are right. Although useful to CS graduates that will continue in the same domain and get jobs as software developers, posting on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) will produce more responses. How do I migrate the question?

Comment: If you want to "catch up," why would you want to know the "absolute minimum"? Learn as much as you can. Assuming that you're still employed, it sounds like you already know at least the minimum required for your position.

Comment: @Caleb: because you have to deal with information overload some way or another :D

Comment: @Raphael - even on [programmers.se] this is overly broad, considered a poll and is generally unsuitable.

Comment: @Oded I would have thought so, but figured that was for them to decide. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: complexity theory! eg difference between linear & logarithmic searches eg in database queries. difference between $O(n^2)$ bubble sort and $O(n \log n)$ quicksort. like the question somewhat. hope you can figure out a way to re-ask it here somehow. think the closing is not fair. there are ways to approach it more objectively. eg the Advanced Placement CS curriculum contents. etc.

Comment: @John re: What CS to study first for application to professional programming, I suggest the basics of big-O complexity costs [so you avoid O(n^2) algorithms where possible; I encountered an O(n^3) string copy routine!], parsing theory / FSMs [often handy], and lambda calculus / Lisp [Java and C++ are finally getting lambda expressions because they're so useful]. Lisp lets you use the same language to program what happens at run time, compile time, & dev time. Not so in C++! Haskell makes things abstract & difficult. Monads in Haskell are known to be hard. Turns out they're easy in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the absolute minimum every software developer absolutely,
> positively must know about computer science (no excuses!)?

IMO every software developer should **absolutely** know (no excuses!) the quote attributed to E. W. Dijkstra:

*"Computer science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes"*

:-D :-D

Answer (score 2):

Programmers need to know enough basic logic (at least some first-order logic) so that they find it natural to write assertions and specifications in a declarative way. Most programmers tend to only see the imperative aspects of programs. This does not help when you have to reason about your programs, or design good interfaces for modules and components.

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer please?

Comment: I mean that, from a programming, and especially software-engineering perspective, it is more useful to know about first-order logic than to know about P vs NP.